# How to get the SQL command of a Column object in PySpark?

Tags: python, sql, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to get an SQL command from a `Column` object in PySpark.

I know it is a strange use case but I want to use placeholders in the expression for templating.

For example I have a `Column`

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr
my_col = col("example_column_{placeholder}").isin("A", "B")
```

and I want to get

```py
sql = "(example_column_{placeholder} IN ('A', 'B'))"
```

so I can later `format` the templated SQL string.

The problem is that the only option in PySpark is

```py
sql = my_col._jc.toString()
```

which returns

```py
print(sql)
# (example_column_{placeholder} IN (A, B))
```

which isn't a correct SQL command (apostrophes are missing around `A` and `B`)
therefore when I run

```py
df.withColumn("my_col", expr(my_col._jc.toString().format(placeholder="value")))
```

it crashes with `AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'A' given input columns`
even though `A` is supposed to be a string literal and not a column.

I know that `col._jc.toString()` isn't probably supposed to be used for getting the SQL. In Scala you can do it like this

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val my_col: Column = col("example_column_{placeholder}").isin("A", "B")

my_col.expr.sql
```

Is there a way to access this method from PySpark? Or somehow work around the issue?

Comment: I think it is not possible but I may be wrong. Pyspark is not a DBMS, it understands SQL but is not supposed to generate it.

Comment: Instead of `df.withColumn("my_col", expr(my_col._jc.toString()))` use `df.withColumn("my_col", my_col)`